# Generated xml as downloadable content ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got XML generated with NokiGiri builder and I'm rendering xml (in controller) :

```
render xml: builder.to_xml
```

And it displays xml file to user in browser. How do I serve downloadable file to user instead of xml content in browser.

**UPDATE**

I've tried both :

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.xml"'
render xml: builder.to_xml
```

and

```
send_data builder.to_xml, 
:type => 'application/octet-stream; header=present',
:disposition => "attachment; filename=test.xml"
```

None of which worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking this in before rendering should do the trick, I believe:

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.xml"'
```

EDIT: There's also [`send_data`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data) (you will want to provide the same `type` and `disposition` params).